# Succinct way to select where COST1 is different than COST2 (treat null=null)

Tags: sql, oracle, null, where-clause, oracle18c

I have two number columns: COST1 and COST2.

Values can be:

- Negative numbers
- Zero
- Positive numbers
- Null

```
with workorder
     (cost1,cost2) as (
select    1,    1 from dual union all
select -100, null from dual union all
select null,    0 from dual union all
select    0,  100 from dual union all
select null, null from dual
)

select
  *
from
  workorder
```

| COST1 | COST2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| -100 | null |
| null | 0 |
| 0 | 100 |
| null | null |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d47174008a7ccbec3d69c1e66efe28ba)

---

I want to select rows where COST1 is different than COST2.

- I want to treat nulls as if they are equal.
- But I don't want to treat nulls as zeros.

Result:

| COST1 | COST2 |
| --- | --- |
| -100 | null |
| null | 0 |
| 0 | 100 |

---

It would be equivalent to the `is not` syntax in SQLite:

```
with workorder 
(cost1,cost2) as (
values
(   1,    1),
(-100, null),
(null,    0),
(   0,  100),
(null, null)
)

select
  *
from
  workorder
where
  cost1 is not cost2
```

| COST1 | COST2 |
| --- | --- |
| -100 | null |
| null | 0 |
| 0 | 100 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5229eaee04d73d1a2988083ee3cc4cce)

---

How can I do that succinctly using Oracle SQL? (succinctness trumps performance)

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your values to strings, then transform your null values to "null" strings using the [`NVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions119.htm#i91798) function. Hence check the inequality.

```
where NVL(CAST(cost1 AS VARCHAR2(10)), 'null') <> NVL(CAST(cost2 AS VARCHAR2(10)), 'null')
```

---

Another option is combining your two conditions that check for null values with a single check: the concatenation of the two values should correspond to one or the other cost values.

```
where cost1 <> cost2
   OR CONCAT(cost1, cost2) IN (cost1, cost2)
```

Check the demos [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=385509c52cf2a5147364a55276f5d893).

Answer (score 1):

How about using `binary_float_nan` as the default for `nvl`?

```
with workorder (cost1,cost2) as (
    select    1,    1 from dual union all
    select -100, null from dual union all
    select null,    0 from dual union all
    select    0,  100 from dual union all
    select null, null from dual
)
select o.*
from   workorder o
where  nvl(cost1,binary_double_nan) <> nvl(cost2,binary_double_nan)
```

Alternatively, if precision and scale are defined for `cost`, for example `number(10,2)`, then a reasonably safe default might be something like `0.0001`, `1/3` or `22/7`.

Comment: Thanks. Good call on the precision thing. I should have included decimal places in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. But it's not as succinct as I'd like:

```
with workorder
     (cost1,cost2) as (
select    1,    1 from dual union all
select -100, null from dual union all
select null,    0 from dual union all
select    0,  100 from dual union all
select null, null from dual
)

select
  *
from
  workorder
where
  cost1 <> cost2
  or (cost1 is null and cost2 is not null)
  or (cost1 is not null and cost2 is null)
```

```
COST1  COST2
-----  -----
 -100   null
 null      0
    0    100
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e73785fc9543c7bd0c2909d2a45e2062)